# Aluminium oxide phase diagram

Tags: computational-chemistry, phase, materials

I have been looking for the phase diagram of alumina or Aluminium oxide, could it be that there is not something like that?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

There is really not much to it.  Basically you have a metal and an oxide phase, and never the twain shall mix significantly even after melting the oxide above 2000°C [[1](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1361%2F105497102770331271)].  The suboxide that is sometimes mentioned, $\ce{Al2O}$, is not indicated here.

[image]
From Ref. 1

Reference

1.
S. Das, "The Al-O-Ti System", J. Phase Equilibria 23(6) (2002), 525-536.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/036459169290005I?via%3Dihub is another reference - it also shows no other binary phases, although it does show an ionic liquid of Al2O3 composition with a miscibility gap to the Al liquid.

Comment: This diagram shows the ionic liquid as well, its saturation line is the short segment on the upper right.